# Locating Exit/Abort Functions from Static Analysis

Tags: binary-analysis, static-analysis, libc

Similar to [this](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11149/locating-memory-allocation-functions-from-static-analysis) question, I'm interested in locating `exit` and `abort` style functions in a firmware - any function call that in fact terminates the execution, by statically analyzing the firmware.

My firmware is `arm-cortex-M` based.

Any ideas how can I find it?